# Meaning of confidence factor in J48

Tags: r, parameters, weka, j48, c4.5

I try to use J48 classifier from RWeka library in R (C4.5 algorithm). I can parametrize this classifier with C parameter which means 'confidence factor'. What does this value exactly mean? I know that bigger value means that I believe more my learning set is a good representation of the whole population and the algorithm will be less likely to prune. But what it exactly means? Is there any formula how to interpret this value?

Comment: This is a question better asked on CrossValidated.com or the Data Science forum.

Comment: …or by means of a [simple web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=weka+j48+confidence+factor&t=ffsb&ia=web)?